# MySQL process increase suddenly(Windows)

Tags: mysql

How to kill all the processes in the show processlist in MySQL? There are around 850 processes in my server.(Windows)

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't seem like a sensible thing to do, you will loose data. Better to try and understand what is going on and take appropriate action.

In that respect [Scientific Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method) is your friend

1. Ask a question - Why do I have so may MySQL processes.
2. Gather data using monitoring tools.
3. Analyse the data gathered and the application.
4. Make changes based on what you learned.
5. Monitor the effect of the changes.
6. Did it solve the problem - if no go back to 3 or 2
7. Document the changes